# Source Transformations resistor on bottom?

Tags: source

I know that source transformations work as shown in the top part of the attached image but what happens when the resistor is placed in a different location?

Does this give the same result? If so, how do I know which where to place the resistor if I performed the transformation the other way around i.e. from Norton eqv to Thevenin eqv?

Sorry for the poor quality of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If inside a black box was a battery and series resistor, it would be impossible to tell which lead of the battery contained the series resistor.

In short, the equivalent circuit is the same.